# Automate copying of spreadsheet cells to following rows

Tags: sql, excel, database, google-sheets, data-transform

This has been bothering me for about a month. I have a very messy export from a scheduling tool that returns events and hours in a way that's human readable, but very difficult to query.

Here is a simplified section of the export:

[image]

To bring this data into a database I manually copy the name to every row below it until I get to the next name (drag to copy. This takes a lot of time because the export contains roughly 90 people with 10-15 lines per person.

The resulting data which I can query against looks like this:

[image]

My queries deal with removing the rows I don't need and tidying up everything but I'm really not sure how to automate getting the name on every row.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try a helper column with this formula in row 2, where the names you wish to copy are in column B.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(B$2:B2<>""),B$2:B2)`

Copy down all the way, Copy / Paste Special > Values to the original column, and delete the helper.

The trick is in the construction of the `B$2:B2` range. It starts at the absolute `B$2` and ends at the relative `B2`. So, as the formula is copied down it will be `B$2:B3` in row 3, `B$2:B4` in row 4 etc, always ending on the row the formula occupies.

Comment: Hi Variatus, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I fully understand how to use this. I put your formula in a column next to the schedule export and copied it downward. It seems to only work on the rows where the names are already available.  Here is a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KQpvo7Ualf7_zc6tLU8llepBIE8tFzdhNLdYSJ57Y8c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The formula was tested, and now I tested it again. It works as advertised. Before we go into Excel versioning, please check the row referencing in your formula. I have added a description of what's critical to my answer above. If you still can't get it to work please let me look at the exact formula you use and tell me the exact cell from which it was copied.